# Android emulator does not start in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I just installed the whole shebang in order to develop android apps in Eclipse (I'm running 64-bit gentoo). Everything seems to go fine, and I created the dev group's hello-world example:

```
package com.nfshost.flyingmonkey.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I go to try and run it in eclipse, and according to the console it seems to work:

```
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.nfshost.flyingmonkey.android.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using device '015D7D330A028012'
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device '015D7D330A028012'
[2010-08-26 14:03:18 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-08-26 14:03:20 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2010-08-26 14:03:20 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.nfshost.flyingmonkey.android.HelloAndroid on device 
[2010-08-26 14:03:21 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.nfshost.flyingmonkey.android/.HelloAndroid }
```

Only, the emulator never shows up on my screen like the guide says it will (http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html#run)

Comment: `Automatic Target Mode: using device '015D7D330A028012'` seems to suggest it's installing onto a USB-attached device, rather than firing up an emulator.

Comment: Hah, that's exactly what was happening. My DROID was plugged in and sitting behind my laptop screen so I didn't see it was doing anything. I wish you'd write that up as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Christopher, could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See first comment to my question:

`Automatic Target Mode: using device '015D7D330A028012' seems to suggest it's installing onto a USB-attached device, rather than firing up an emulator.` – Christopher Aug 26 at 19:17

Comment: I had the same issue, looked at my phone which happened to be connected via usb, and presto, the app was there.  Very nice...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Virtual Device and create a New Virtual Device there (Remember to specify the correct target API level for that device). If that virtual device is an accepted virtual device, the app will fire off that device when you run the app.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I've already created the virtual device, and it's got a happy green checkmark next to it. The API levels match.

Comment: Look at Christopher's comment

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the sAMe issue go ro run the select run configuration browse your project select android a new configuration open then select run..

it was working for me..

Answer (score 0):

sorry for above answer i just do it as like this..
open cmd promt..
go to that directory in which my sdk was extraxted i go to tool subdriectory then run android.bat file by just simply put the name android.bat in that file..