# Android emulator fails to start

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I searched google this morning and could not find an answer, so I would like folks on stackoverflow to help.

Until yesterday, everything was perfect, when I ran my android app from eclipse the emulator used to load, and I could test everything.

I used it today and the emulator does not load.

Here is the dump from the console

```
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] ------------------------------
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] Android Launch!
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] adb is running normally.
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] Performing com.Dyforms.XMLGui activity launch
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'newAVD'
[2010-12-02 10:39:42 - HomeScreen] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'newAVD'
```

I can see emulator.exe available in the task manager, but I do not see it launched.

Can you guys guide me what could be wrong?

Rupin

Comment: please try to format your code when posting it.

Comment: I had a similar kind of problem before. It worked after a clean/build . Or a complete application restart would fix, i guess.

Comment: Would this help, maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578586/android-emulator-does-not-start-in-eclipse

Comment: @Jason- Which part would you like to reformat.It appears formatted correctly to me.

Comment: @Dhanesh- thanks for your response.I tried that, it did not work.
@Mala- I saw that post earlier..I have not as yet attached a physical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A restart of the machine did the trick..It works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Check out RunConfiguration for project. inside it "Deployment Target Mode " is Automatic/Manual , Please if there is emulator you tried yesterday exists or not. - thanks

Comment: Deployment Target Mode is Automatic

Comment: The emulator is also listed, and is checked

Answer (score 1):

Try running the emulator standalone from the command line, in particular try doing it with the option to wipe the userdata partition in case things got messed up.  It will boot a bit slower the first time after that as it has to re-dex-opt everything, but hopefully it should boot.   Also, as soon as it seems like it's trying to run, adb shell into it and do a ps to see what it's up to.

There are also command line options to start the emulator with kernel log output, etc.

Or you could try creating a clean new avd.

Answer (score 0):

Quit skype if it is running.  It must use the same port as skype.  When I quit it worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

I struggled with the same problem. The CPU ran near 100% and the emulator never completed loading. It was only when I removed all the Apple products (iTunes, iCloud etc) from my PC that resolved the issue resolved. My PC became a lot more responsive too!